# Tidying up data in R - should I use loops?

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R that is unstructured, i.e. data that should be grouped into four columns are spread across the data frame:

[Original Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR2V5.png)

When I apply the below code, I am transposing the data and then using subset to group all the values together, and then transpose it back again. The result looks like this:

[New Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtzsQ.png)

However, I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this through a looping mechanism.

Any advice appreciated on steps I could take to improve the below. Ideally, I would be able to use a loop to be able to tidy up all columns that would be included in a particular data frame.

```
tmydata=t(mydata)
df=data.frame(tmydata)

firstrow=subset(df, X1!="NA")
thefirstrow=firstrow[1]

secondrow=subset(df, X2!="NA")
thesecondrow=secondrow[2]

thirdrow=subset(df, X3!="NA")
thethirdrow=thirdrow[3]

fourthrow=subset(df, X4!="NA")
thefourthrow=fourthrow[4]

df2=data.frame(thefirstrow,thesecondrow,thethirdrow,thefourthrow)
finaloutput=t(df2)
finaldata=data.frame(finaloutput)
finaldata
col_headings <- c("A","B","C","D")
finaldata
names(finaldata) <- col_headings
```

Comment: Please add a code snippet that constructs some example data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following does what you want:

Some sample data:

```
set.seed(1234)
df = matrix(runif(32),4,8)
colnames(df) = LETTERS[1:8]
df[df<0.2]=NA
```

Code:

```
library(plyr)
df = rbind.fill(lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) {as.data.frame(t(df[x,][!is.na(df[x,])])) }))
colnames(df) = LETTERS[1:ncol(df)]
```

Input:

```
             A         B         C         D         E         F         G         H
[1,]        NA 0.8609154 0.6660838 0.2827336 0.2862233 0.3166125 0.2187995 0.8313450
[2,] 0.6222994 0.6403106 0.5142511 0.9234335 0.2668208 0.3026934 0.8105986        NA
[3,] 0.6092747        NA 0.6935913 0.2923158        NA        NA 0.5256975 0.4560915
[4,] 0.6233794 0.2325505 0.5449748 0.8372956 0.2322259        NA 0.9146582 0.2651867
```

Output:

```
          A         B         C         D         E         F         G
1 0.8609154 0.6660838 0.2827336 0.2862233 0.3166125 0.2187995 0.8313450
2 0.6222994 0.6403106 0.5142511 0.9234335 0.2668208 0.3026934 0.8105986
3 0.6092747 0.6935913 0.2923158 0.5256975 0.4560915        NA        NA
4 0.6233794 0.2325505 0.5449748 0.8372956 0.2322259 0.9146582 0.2651867
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# create a function which subsets x by removing NAs
naFilter = function(x) {
    return(subset(x, !is.na(x)));
}

tidydata = as.data.frame( # convert the object into a data.frame
    t( # transpose the apply output (see ?apply)
        # apply the filter function per-row
        apply(yourdata, 1, naFilter)
    )
);
# rename data.frame columns
colnames(tidydata) = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```